# Where is a place where ffmpeg player connects to server and starts buffering?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

My app shows HLS streams, for showing I use ffmpeg player. A problem is that the player doesn't change streams url relatively to current bandwidth. So I implemented logic about calculating bandwidth, but I cannot find where I have to implement url changing. I figured out that [read_data](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/hls.c#L1214) method responsibles for buffering data. In this case I have to change url before calling read_data but I cannot find from what place it calls.
So my question is
Where is that place where the player connects to server and starts buffering data?
Maybe someone faced with same problem. Or knows ffmpeg well and know this place where is better to place change url logic. Please let me know, I open for all proposals

Comment: Which ffmpeg player? ffplay? VLC? Something else?

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer

Comment: read_data called from hls_read_header

Comment: @galeksandrp I don't agree with you. In my app hls_read_header was called only once but read_data was called a lot of times. Please, let me know if I understood something wrong

Comment: @Dima read_data passed as callback to ffio_init_context, which is called in for cycle multiple times in [hls.c#L1603](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/hls.c#L1603)

Comment: @galeksandrp yes, I found. Thank you but as I understood the best place to change url, it's inside of read_data in restart mark directly in playlist structure. Because if I change it not in structure it will crush. You can issue a response to I will be able to mark it as answer

Comment: @Dima [issued](/a/35905648/3209640).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_data` passed as callback to `ffio_init_context`, which is called multiple times in for cycle in `hls_read_header` [hls.c#L1619](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n3.0.2/libavformat/hls.c#L1619)

Answer (score 0):

Use the top level m3u8 playlist URL, http://yourdomain/playlist.m3u8

And your top level playlist will look like this, includes 3 stream urls,

```
#EXTM3U 
 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=200000 
 /hls/stream1.m3u8 
 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=500000 
 /hls/stream2.m3u8 
 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=800000 
 /hls/stream3.m3u8
```

There are 3 streams that depend on bandwidth, 
just give the top level url to player

Look at [here](https://support.octoshape.com/entries/20647751-Broadcasting-using-an-HLS-source-) for more information.

Comment: I know how HLS work, but ffmepg player doesn't change url when bandwidth changes